# Создание сокетов

Tags: visual-studio, сокет, c++, visual-studio-2010

Всем добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно почитать про создание сокетов и запросов на с++, желательно с основ и от простого к сложному. Как правильно создать сокет, как правильно отправить запрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю насчет качества материла, но думаю сойдет в начале.
[Первая часть](http://www.vr-online.ru/content/s-setevoe-programmirovanie-chast-1-3999)
[Вторая часть](http://www.vr-online.ru/content/setevoe-programmirovanie-chast-2-modeli-vvoda-vyvoda-4343)
[Треться часть](http://www.vr-online.ru/content/setevoe-programmirovanie-chast-3-klient-server-4356)

Comment: Для начала вполне годится, здорово ориентировано на виду, но это видимо и надо автору вопроса. 

Как всегда в целях упрощения примеров тот факт, что recv() может вернуть длину меньше запрошенной фактически замалчивается (по крайней мере на этом внимание не акцентируется).

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую статью [Самоучитель игры на WINSOCK](http://www.insidepro.com/kk/006/006r.shtml), автор Крис Касперски.

Comment: Помню такую. Подтверждаю, хорошая статья.